# Android phones hangs -phone hardly usable

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I have a moto g2 android phone with 5.0.2 android Lolipop.

It has started to hang so severely that the mobile is almost unusable.

The mobile never really had any hanging issues earlier.All of a sudden this problem popped up.

I tried :

1. factory resetting the phone
2. removing sdcard
3. removing junk files & folders from sdcard & internally memory
4. I have uninstalled most of the apps.(I have google keep,calender widget & watsapp)

Can this be a hardware issue?

I don't want to root my phone as it is still in warranty.

Please share how can I fix this problem .

Thanks

EDIT

- when the problem popped up I was on 5.0.1 lollipop version
- There is no common point when my phone freezes
- After the rest the, when I linked the google account etc & installed watsapp , hanging problem started . Only when there was a fresh reset & no app or account was added the phone worked fine

Comment: 1) "*The mobile never really had any hanging issues earlier.All of a sudden this problem popped up.*" -- in that earlier scenario, was the OS Lollipop or Kitkat? 2) Have you noticed something common when the freeze happens? E.g. You're using some common apps, doing file transfer and more. 3) After factory reset and before re-installing the third party apps does your device freeze?

Comment: @Firelord please check the edit for the anwsers . Thanks

Comment: WhatsApp may be the problem

Comment: You might also consider flashing the [factory recovery image](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/standalone/bootloader/recovery-images). I've had issues with OTA updates causing performance issues, and this fixed it on 2 phones and a tablet. I'm sure Motorola provides instructions but just in case, this [XDA guide for restoring stock firmware on Moto G](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2542219) might be helpful.